# How to sign code .sys driver with signtool?

Tags: code-signing, code-signing-certificate, signtool, authenticode

Reading [the documentation to sign my .SYS file](http://certhelp.ksoftware.net/support/solutions/articles/46111-can-i-sign-driver-files-sys-with-these-certificates-) I got this instruction:

```
signtool.exe sign /v /ac "AddTrustExternalCARoot_kmod.crt" /f my.pfx /p password 
/tr http://timestamp.comodoca.com/rfc3161 "C:\myfile.sys"
```

Any idea what `AddTrustExternalCARoot_kmod.crt` is and where do I get it from ?

Answer (score 0):

You get that file as part of your order, e.g. I got it after ordering my certificate at [DigiCert](https://www.digicert.com/code-signing/). It was part of a ZIP archive that contained a total of 4 certificates (my certificate + 3 certificates in the chain).

According the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387764%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `/ac` is for adding additional signatures.

> Specifies a file that contains an additional certificate to add to the signature block.

I never used that for signing my **user mode** applications, but I'm not entirely sure whether you need it for **kernel mode** drivers.